# Create Multiple S3 Buckets having same properties with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create multiple S3 bucktes with same propeties.But I'm not able to create multiple s3 buckets.

I found in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html
*if you have multiple resources of the same type, you can declare them together by separating them with commas*

But I didn't find any example and I'm not sure how to do it.I tried debugging but not getting the result.
Please suggest.
Below is my yaml file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  myS3Bucketlo:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: AuthenticatedRead
Outputs:
  WebsiteURL:
    Value: !GetAtt myS3Bucketlo.WebsiteURL
    Description: URL for the website hosted on S3
```

Answer (score 3):

In a CloudFormation template, each resource must be declared separately. So, even if your buckets have identical properties, they still must be individually declared:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  bucket1:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: AuthenticatedRead
  bucket2:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: AuthenticatedRead
  bucket3:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: AuthenticatedRead
Outputs:
  WebsiteURL1:
    Value: !GetAtt bucket1.WebsiteURL
    Description: URL for the website 1 hosted on S3
  WebsiteURL2:
    Value: !GetAtt bucket2.WebsiteURL
    Description: URL for the website 2 hosted on S3
  WebsiteURL3:
    Value: !GetAtt bucket3.WebsiteURL
    Description: URL for the website 3 hosted on S3
```

However,

> You must declare each resource separately; however, if you have multiple resources of the same type, you can declare them together by separating them with commas.

The wording of this text does imply there is a shortcut to avoid duplication, but I have never seen such a working example.

Comment: I didn't get any such example either and I ended up using teraform where I found  it easy to declare multiple resources of the same type using count.

Comment: The example helped me too. Each bucket must have a different name or it just creates one bucket.

Comment: @Matt Houser: If we have to create buckets for each environment like <dev/stage/prod> , I want to create bucket names like raw-data-<environment variable> how do we pass the environment variable value using cloud formation templates?

Comment: @NK7983 You could pass the dev/stage/prod as a parameter, then use the Join or Sub function to join them together. Or pass the entire bucket name as a parameter.